# Why system.profile collection is not updated in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have enabled profiling for mongodb cluster with 3 servers by using below configuration:
operationProfiling:
  mode: all
  slowOpThresholdMs: 200
  slowOpSampleRate: 0.98

1. Only 50 entries are visible in system.profile collection. After couple of hours, there are no more updates. Current size of collection :1.5 KB, default is 1MB.
   What could be possible reasons for this and how i can find the root cause ?

2.In a replica of three, I am able to run queries against profile collection only on primary server.
What is the reason for this ?

Any help in resolving above queries is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a 'system.profile' collection for each database where operations for that database are entered.

- Make sure you are checking the right database.
- Check with the [profile](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/profile/#profile) database command or the [getProfilingLevel](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getProfilingStatus/index.html#db-getprofilingstatus) shell helper to make sure it is set the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks @Joe. I am checking in collection against relevant database and profiling level is 2.I can see diagnostic messages in the mongod.log, but not in collection

Comment: If you run `db.system.profile.find()` twice, does the second one show the profiling of the first?

Comment: It will show results updated for 30 minutes. After that it does not show latest data i..e system.profile collection is not being updated,